# actionlib shutdown beacuse of getState()

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, simpleactionclient

[image: Rosanswers logo]

the code is be like:

> ```
> return this->moveBaseClient->getState();
> ```

while moveBaseClient is:

> ```
> typedef actionlib::SimpleActionClient<move_base_msgs::MoveBaseAction> MoveBaseClient;
> std::shared_ptr<MoveBaseClient> moveBaseClient;
> ```

calling at 20hz and this happened:

```
robot_decision_node: /opt/ros/kinetic/include/actionlib/managed_list.h:168: const T& actionlib::ManagedList<T>::Handle::getElem() const [with T = boost::shared_ptr<actionlib::CommStateMachine<move_base_msgs::MoveBaseAction_<std::allocator<void> > > >]: Assertion `valid_' failed.
```

Am i using getState wrong?

i chage the frequency to 10hz, now it works fine.

but it's still a bug?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/366701/actionlib-shutdown-beacuse-of-getstate()/) by [zhazha](https://answers.ros.org/users/38016/zhazha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2020-11-30

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) on 2020-12-01**:
You should also post the code that sets `moveBaseClient`.

**Comment by [zhazha](https://answers.ros.org/users/38016/zhazha/) on 2020-12-01**:
hi,i have updated the question with defination of moveBaseClient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You may not be able to create an instance.

`MoveBaseClient moveBaseClient("move_base", true);` and initialize it with `this->moveBaseClient.getState()`, which should work.

If it has to be a pointer, it would work with `std::shared_ptr<MoveBaseClient> moveBaseClient = new MoveBaseClient("move_base", true);`.

---

Originally posted by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) with karma: 1908 on 2020-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zhazha](https://answers.ros.org/users/38016/zhazha/) on 2020-12-06**:
i have initialized the pointer like this：

if (!moveBaseClient.get()) {
moveBaseClient = std::make_shared("/move_base");
}

and i run the node in 10hz，it works fine

**Comment by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) on 2020-12-06**:
Congratulations. If you would like, please make a collect. Or, please state your  answer.